# Insert list values in a tkinter as info text but with \n separations

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a list called "list_of_values" where this appears in the console:

```
[('#', 0, ':', 12.148057), ('#', 1, ':', 15.776696999999999), ('#', 2, ':', 28.555822), ('#', 3, ':', 28.89765), ('#', 4, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 5, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 6, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 7, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 8, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 9, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 10, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 11, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 12, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 13, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 14, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 15, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 16, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 17, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 18, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 19, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 20, ':', 28.923944999999996), ('#', 21, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 22, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 23, ':', 28.950239), ('#', 24, ':', 28.950239)]
```

And I want to integrate this list (each part of the list in a line), in to a tkinter widget.

---

The tkinter code:

```
list_of_values = []
j = 0
while j < 25:
    string_to_save = '#',j, ":", head[head.index(minHead)-j]
    print (string_to_save)
    j = j + 1 # this can be written as j += 1
    list_of_values.append(string_to_save)


root3 = tk.Tk()
root3.geometry('800x500') 
info3=tk.Label(root3,text='Give index value of the list:',anchor='e')
info3.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(text=list_of_values)
label2.pack()

save_button2 = tk.Button(root3)
save_button2.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_index(ents2))
save_button2.pack()
root3.mainloop()
```

With the label2, my widget prints the list but one value next to each other, and I would like that they appear (separated by lines) :

```
('#', 0, ':', 12.148057)
('#', 1, ':', 15.776696999999999)
('#', 2, ':', 28.555822)
('#', 3, ':', 28.89765)
('#', 4, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 5, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 6, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 7, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 8, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 9, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 10, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 11, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 12, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 13, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 14, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 15, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 16, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 17, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 18, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 19, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 20, ':', 28.923944999999996)
('#', 21, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 22, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 23, ':', 28.950239)
('#', 24, ':', 28.950239)
```

There is a fast way to do it? Or should I type each location + \n?

Comment: Read about [the-string-format-method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) and [The Tkinter Listbox Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

Comment: Have you tried `"\n".join(list_of_values)` (or perhaps `"\n".join([str(x) for x in list_of_values])`?

Comment: The second one worked, thak you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_values = []
j = 0
while j < 25:
    string_to_save = '#',j, ":", head[head.index(minHead)-j]
    print (string_to_save)
    j = j + 1 # this can be written as j += 1
    list_of_values.append(string_to_save)


root3 = tk.Tk()
root3.geometry('800x500') 
info3=tk.Label(root3,text='Give index value of the list:',anchor='e')
info3.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(text="\n".join([str(x) for x in list_of_values]))
label2.pack()

save_button2 = tk.Button(root3)
save_button2.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_index(ents2))
save_button2.pack()
root3.mainloop()
```